# How to round dash cap in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to round dash cap in border?

Or how to round dash cap in a custom line?

This is what I want to create.

[image: Like this]

I made that with background image and I can't round dashes.

```css
.dashed-line {
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4b9ed9 60%, transparent 40%);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 6px 30px;
  }
```

```html
<span class="dashed-line"></span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The way the border dashes are drawed is up to the browser. Sure you can work with a background image but there is no easy way and you will have to manage it if you also want an actual background. There is also border-image but it is not compatible with rounded borders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `radial-gradient` combined with `linear-gradient`

```css
.dashed-line {
  --s:15px; /* control the space between dashes */

  width: 6px;
  height: 180px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#4b9ed9 98%,#0000) 0 0/100% var(--s),
   linear-gradient(#4b9ed9 50%, #0000 0) 0 calc(var(--s)/2)/100% calc(2*var(--s));
}

.dashed-line-alt {
  --s:15px;

  height: 6px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#4b9ed9 98%,#0000) 0 0/var(--s) 100%,
   linear-gradient(90deg,#4b9ed9 50%, #0000 0) calc(var(--s)/2) 0/calc(2*var(--s)) 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashed-line"></div>
<hr>
<div class="dashed-line-alt"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use dotted border.

```css
p.dotted {
padding: 5px;
border-style: dotted;
border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="dotted">A dotted border.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this isn't the target.

Answer (score -1):

Could this help?

CSS:

```
.dashed-line {
    display: grid;
    .line {
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4b9ed9 60%, #4b9ed9 10%);
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
  <span class="dashed-line">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"> </span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
  </span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it can but this is not flexible.
This answer is a better way for my question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912762/how-to-round-dash-cap-in-css#70912865)